# Call Python function with args using Cython

Tags: python, cython

I use Cython to use Python functions inside C code. I need to call Python funcs with arguments from C, but compilers says I need use PyObject, when i'm calling Python function. How I must do this if I need to pass an integer to Python function for example?

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "hello.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf ("Initializing Python Runtime...\n");
    Py_Initialize ();

    inithello();

    PyObject *a;
    start_app(a);

    printf ("Cleanup...\n");
    Py_Finalize ();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm doing something like this.
start_app is a function in python which take PyObject argument, how i can initialize PyObject to use it inside python? Cause now, when i try to print(a) inside python, a have Segfault

Comment: You need to add a [mcve] to make your question clearer.

Comment: I suspect this should be tagged [tag:python-c-api] and possibly not [tag:cython] (since I don't see how you'd do this from C with Cython) but it really isn't clear.

Comment: My best guess is that you're looking for something like [`PyObject_CallFunction`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallFunction).

Comment: Your example isn’t complete (what is hello.h?) and what has cython to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you have a Cython module called "hello" with [`cdef public`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#public-declarations) functions so that you can call the functions from C:

```
cdef public void start_app(arg):
    # do something...
```

You want to know how to pass `arg`. You have two options:

1. Define the type of `arg` to be a C type (in Cython):

   ```
   cdef public void start_app(int arg):
   ```

   This is probably the easiest solution - you can just pass a C int.
2. Create a Python integer in C:

   ```
   PyObject* arg = PyLong_FromLong(5); // in Python2 this would be PyInt_FromLong
   start_app(arg);
   Py_DECREF(arg); // drop our reference to it
   ```

---

Note that I've assumed that `start_app` returns `void`. If it returns a Python object (which it does by default unless you tell it otherwise) you must check that `PyObject*` against NULL (it's NULL if there's an error) and then handle the reference counting of that `PyObject*` (DECREF it when you're done with it)